# my Gmail's company account got the password change without my permission, can they see my emails?

Tags: email, passwords, gmail

I am working with company xyzzz.com, they have a gmail business account for me myname@xyzzz.com. Now company xyzzz changed the password and I can't access the email.

So my question is: do they have access to the emails?

Comment: If they can set a new password against your username, then technically yes they can then have access to your account (since they know your username and now they know your "new"-ly reset password).

Comment: @Darius, Does Gmail for business dashboard allow that level of managing? Does gmail allow the option to change an account password an then the company can access any employee account/email and data?

Comment: The "Google Administrator" of your Google Apps domain can basically do whatever they want as far as I know... I know my company uses Google Apps, and I am part of the IT support and we can "set" new password to any account. By knowing the username and password, I can just login into your account obviously. Technically they can. Legally - depends on how the company worded their legal document. I'm assuming those higher-up than me can even create/delete account.. so yes they can wipe your whole email and data along in it with pretty much a mouse flick.

Comment: Very simply, yes - I am admin on a similar setup & I have no difficulty logging to anyone's account & viewing their mail - I don't, ethically - but I can.

Comment: Well, they *can* get access to all those third party accounts using your account by changing the password, but for most of them, they would be violating Federal law if they did so. (Probably not for the Google drive. Probably so for the YouTube channel. Unless your have a contract that authorizes them to do so.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Google Apps administrator for you company's account can change passwords. If the admin changes your password, he/she can then use it to log into *all* Google services associated with that account (since it's a valid username and password), including Google Drive and Youtube.